# Clicker script only clicking once (Logitech Lua Scripting)

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Wrote this in Lua for my Logitech mouse. It's an autoclicker script that should autoclick with intervals between clicks following a normal distribution while holding the back button.

```
local currentTime = GetRunningTime()
math.randomseed(currentTime)

function gaussianRandom(mean, stddev)
    local u1 = math.random()
    local u2 = math.random()

    local z0 = math.sqrt(-2.0 * math.log(u1)) * math.cos(2.0 * math.pi * u2)

    return mean + z0 * stddev
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    while IsMouseButtonPressed(4) do
          PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
          Sleep(gaussianRandom(800, 200))
    end
end
```

However it only clicks once. If I instead use this code:

```
min = 500
max = 1000

local currentTime = GetRunningTime()
math.randomseed(currentTime)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    while IsMouseButtonPressed(4) do
        PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(min,max))
    end
end
```

It autoclicks continuously while holding down the back button. I'm just confused as to why the normal distribution code doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sleep` expects integer amount of milliseconds.
Try

```
Sleep(math.floor(gaussianRandom(800, 200)))
```